# Confused with launchMode

Tags: android, android-intent, launchmode

I made a Music Player that operates in two ways:

1. If started as a normal app, it continues playing what it was playing when last closed, and it should start in the background;
2. If an audio file is selected in a fileManager, it plays the song clicked in the foreground.

Since I want only one instance of the app running, so I added to the mainfest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

What I did to accomplish this was to execute this `onCreate`:

```
    uri = getIntent.getData();
    if (uri != null) {
        newsong = uri.toString()...
        play(newsong);
    } else {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        playoldsong();
    }
```

It works great, except for the fact that, when started as in (1) and, after a while, I select a song in a filemanager, the main activity is brought to the front (which is what I want) BUT it continues playing what it was playing before the song selection. The player ignored the new song, and I want it to switch to it.

This actually makes sense, since the only place where I call the new song is in the `onCreate`.

Maybe the `launchMode` is not the correct one? Maybe I should `@Overwrite` the OnNewTask(Intent) method? Which is the 'cheaper' solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override [onNewIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) to start the song the user clicked on in the file manager.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I just did, and works. I was hoping there was another way... Thanks!